# HTML audio tag only works after I first manually navigate to it once

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

Super-weird thing happens with my html audio. No matter what I tried I could not get it to work. So I inspected my code and from that link I played the file to make sure the link was working. Then I went back to my site within the same tab and it worked perfectly every time I hit the refresh button. But if I do this in a new tab it will not work at all. this phenomenon is consistent across browsers and devices so it can't be a software issue. Please help.

Here's my code.

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
    displayRandImages();
    startCountdown();
    document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<audio id="my_audio" src="/audio/thesound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: Check browser console; it's almost certainly due to autoplay-blocking policies.

Comment: As suggested above. Check the browser console, it is your best friend when trying to find problems and for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I
checked my browser console and due to Chrome's new autoplay policy you
have to get a click from the user before you play audio. So I added a modal and made visitors click to enter, and played the sound then.